# UpdateSourceExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, binding

According to the docs, if I return null from the handler, it should ignore the exception, of which my understanding is that it wouldn't add the error to the Error collection. But having tried it, it still shows up in the entry `[0].ErrorContent`. Am I misunderstanding this?

Ultimately, all I'm trying to do is ignore validation errors of a particular exception type.

```
<TextBox Height="20">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                           Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}">
                </TextBlock>
                <Border BorderBrush="Green"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Number"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                 UpdateSourceExceptionFilter="ReturnExceptionHandler">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>        
</TextBox>
```

```
object ReturnExceptionHandler(object bindingExpression, Exception exception)
{
    if (exception is FormatException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return exception;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReturnExceptionHandler` is called? On one of my projects, I've found that I need to set the `BindingGroupName` to a value in order to make the `UpdateSourceExceptionFilter` work.

Don't ask me why.